# Xdebug on https website, not working correct with PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm, xdebug

There are two websites on the same server. One of them is HTTP and it's debugging correctly. But another is HTTPS and debug is not correct. It breaks only if is checked "Break at first line" and some of pages get 500 error. Path mapping is also not working. Server is Apache + nginx. Both sites are opencart shops.

[image: https]

[image: http]

```
    <- feature_set -i 4 -n extended_properties -v 1
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="4" status="starting" reason="ok"><error code="3"><message><![CDATA[invalid or missing options]]></message></error></response>

<- feature_set -i 5 -n resolved_breakpoints -v 1
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="5" status="starting" reason="ok"><error code="3"><message><![CDATA[invalid or missing options]]></message></error></response>

<- feature_set -i 6 -n notify_ok -v 1
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="6" status="starting" reason="ok"><error code="3"><message><![CDATA[invalid or missing options]]></message></error></response>
```

here are errors.

Comment: Could you please show screenshots from both servers(websites) mappings?
(Languages & Frameworks | PHP | Servers)

Comment: Added screenshots in main question

Comment: 1) Enable Xdebug log, try to debug that site (1 page only), see what will be there in that log. Right now it still could be path mapping (e.g. due to symlinks) or execution starts with some another file (e.g. some sort of "global include"). 2) Are those website handled by the same web server? Maybe they have different PHP and therefore Xdebug configs? Check `phpinfo()` output captured via browser.

Comment: yes both sites handled by the same server, same php and xdebug configs). About log files , here,logs

Comment: in main question added

Comment: Did you solve this issue? If yes, how?

Comment: Unfortunately no,